# How to prevent xlrd adding precison to float values

Tags: python, xlrd

My issue is little bit strange. I have an excel file in which some float values are mentioned e.g. **0.0079** but when I try to read it using my code it's giving me **0.007899999999999999**.
 I'm not sure what's actually happening here(may be that's the original data which was entered in the excel sheet when it was originally created). I checked other questions on SO which are similar but they are all concerned about '***how to not loose the precision***' and my case is opposite.

sample code:

```
sheet_hdl = open_workbook('file.xls')
sheet = sheet_hdl.sheet_by_index(0)
for row_idx in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    for col_idx in range(1):
        if(val == str(sheet.cell(row_idx,col_idx + 1).value)):
            accuracy_val = repr(sheet.cell(row_idx,col_idx + 7).value)
            print(accuracy_val)
```

Note: It's not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). The question in this link involves computation, but my data in excel doesn't involve any computations.

Comment: The above link involves computation, that's something processor is doing, but in my case it's simply the data to be read in excel. No computations involved at all.

Comment: You aren't getting "added precision". You're simply seeing the way floating-point math works in binary. Just like some numbers repeat in base 10 (e.g. ⅓ = 0.333…), some other numbers repeat in base 2.

Comment: Does the cell contain a formula? In that case _Excel_ is doing the computation for you, and might display the result differently from how it is stored.

Comment: Exactly, that's my concern, there's no formula involved.

Comment: Input 0.0079 [here](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) for example. Btw, in fact you *are* losing precision; 0.00790000000000000000... cannot be represented exactly in a 32-bit float, so the next best match is taken that does fit in 32 bits.

Comment: You beat me to it, Hanno. @manty, 0.0079 in decimal _cannot be represented precisely in binary_.

Comment: Another example: What output do you get when you do something like `x = 0.0079; print(x);`?

Comment: What if you use `Decimal`? First `from decimal import *` and then `accuracy_val = Decimal(repr(sheet.cell(row_idx,col_idx + 7).value))`

Comment: @HannoBinder doing `x=0.0079` and then `print(x)` is giving exactly `0.0079` in IDLE.

Comment: @vrs Applying your method is giving error as: `decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.ConversionSyntax'>]`